# PHP mail entire page

Tags: php, email, include-path

I have a page that determines the variable ISSET and then acts on instructions. For example if the isset contains 'print' it loads a file via Include Template Path and echos a code on the bottom that prints the window.

eg.

```
if (isset($_GET['quoteprint'])) {
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/bookings/booking-quote.php');
echo'<script type="text/javascript">window.print()</script>';
}
```

Now I would like a similar function to exist but this time to email the contents of that page to the user. I tired this but it does not work. I think the content needs to be converted but I don't know where to start.

```
else if (isset($_GET['quoteemail'])) {
    $emailer = include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/bookings/booking-quote.php');
    $to = $current_user->user_email;
  $subject = "Your Quote - Dive The Gap" ;
  $message = $emailer;
  $headers = "From: Dive The Gap Bookings <ask@divethegap.com>" . "\r\n" .
             "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n";

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: have you tried get_file_contents?

Comment: @Zoidberg: That is file_get_contents

Comment: Even though `\r\n` is the correct way normally, have you tried using `\n`? From the PHP documentation: *If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some poor quality Unix mail transfer agents replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822.*

Comment: Get file contents does not work as it cannot get the data as the include template path is also responsible for what data is shown. \r\n is not the problem either as PHP mail is working fine in all other instances on the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The include function does not return the output or content of the script you're including.
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php for more info (example #4 might be interesting for you).

You need to get the entire content of the page, or the part(s) you'd like to e-mail, into a variable. One way of doing this is using PHP's output buffering. A good explanation of how output buffering works can be found here: http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/PHP-Output-Buffering/